# Why does $G$ need to be finite in this proof of a normal subgroup $N$ containing all elements of order coprime to $[G:N]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is a proof from [Keith Condrad's document](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/A4noindex2.pdf) with cosets instead of classes:

> **Theorem 2.** 
>   If $G$ is a finite group and $N \triangleleft G$ then any element of $G$ with order relatively prime to $[G:N]$ lies in $N$.  In
>   particular, if $N$ has index $2$ then all elements of $ G$ with odd
>   order lie in $N$.
>
> **Proof**:   Let $g$ be an element of $G$ with order $m$, which is relatively prime to $[G:N]$. The equation $g^m=e$ gives
>   $(gN)^m=N \in G/N$.   Also $(gN)^{[G:N]}=N$, as $[G:N]$ is the order
>   of $G/N$.
>
> So the order of $gN \in G/N$ divides $m$ and $[G:N]$.
>
> These numbers are relatively prime, so $gN=N$, which means $g \in N$.

Why is it required that $G$ is finite? Does the theorem also hold for groups in general? I suspected it because of $[G:N]$, but we set it out to be coprime to $m$, is $[G:N]=\infty$ allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the quotient group $G/N$ is finite and $g\in G$ is an element of finite order then it works even if $G$ is infinite. If one of them is infinite then you can't talk about their orders being coprime anyway.